# How to access childWidgets in a QTreeView using QModelIndex?

Tags: c++, qt, data-modeling, qtreeview, qstandarditem

I'm working on an application using the Qt library (version 4.8).

I have a QTreeView with a QStandardItemModel. My widget looks like that:

> Item1
>
> subitem11
>
> subitem12
>
> Item2
>
> subitem21
>
> subitem22
>
> Item3
>
> subitem31
>
> subitem32

Here is how I add the items to my QTreeView:

```
 model->setItem(0, 0, item1); 
 item1->setChild(0, 0, subitem12);
```

I want to take an action only when the user double cliked an item (and do nothing when he clicked a subitem). So I use the  *doubleClicked(const QModelIndex & index)* signal.

I want to process the information about the item/subitem which was double cliked by the user. So I get the row of my item/subitem:

```
index.row();
```

But every time I try to reference to the item/subitem to display its name or check if it has children, I can only access the items:

```
index.model()->item(row)->text();
```

My question is: how can I acces the subitems (vbetween items abd subitems) in my slot? Or how can I prevent them from emitting the signal? I can't disable them - it would be too confusing for the user.

**Edit:** The problem is that every time I click on an item or subitem and execute:

```
index.model()->item(row)->hasChildren();
```

or:

```
index.model()->item(row)->parent() == 0;
```

I get *true* as result. So I can reference only the items.

My question is: **What is the correct way to reference to subitems?**

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to access model items by row index, the model returns top-level item at that row. Use `itemFromIndex` instead:

```
auto item = index.model()->itemFromIndex(index);
if (item && item->hasChildren()){
    // item is not a leaf
}
```

**EDIT** `index.model()` returns `QAbstractItemModel*`, so a cast is also necessary here (or, better, storing a pointer to the standard model somehwere in the code).

Comment: The *QStandardItemModel* class has not function *itemFromIndex*.

Comment: In 5.x: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#itemFromIndex. See also my edit to the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
// Define your custom role to store item type.
enum MyRoles
{
    ItemTypeRole = Qt::UserRole + 1
};

// Define item types.
enum ItemType
{
    Primary,
    Secondary
};
```

Than set the proper *item type* for all your items:

```
QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem("Item1");
item->setData(Primary, ItemTypeRole);

QStandardItem* subItem = new QStandardItem("SubItem1");
subItem->setData(Secondary, ItemTypeRole);
```

And in your slot connected to the *doubleClicked* signal acces the type like this:

```
ItemType type = static_cast<ItemType>(index.data(ItemTypeRole).toInt());
if (type == Primary)
    std::cout << "It's a Primary item!" << std::endl;
else if (type == Secondary)
    std::cout << "It's a Secondary item!" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the signal for the subitems. However, you can check if an item has a parent. It it doesn't, it is an item and if it does, it's a subitem.

```
if (item->parent() != 0)
   .. //subitem
else
   .. //item
```

An alternative would be to use the data() function to set some special value to distinguish between the two.

```
item1->setData(QVariant("item"));
subitem1->setData(QVariant("subitem"));
```

Then query the value in your doubleclick handler:

```
QVariant var = item->data();
if (var.toString() == "item")
  ...
else if (var.toString() == "subitem")
  ...
```

Comment: I didn't make myself clear: the problem is that every time I click on the QTreeView, I can access only the items. I checked if an item has a parent or if it has children, but it didn't help.